# Python: How to loop through each two column combination from dataframe having multiple columns to do clustering?

Tags: pandas, loops, dataframe, iteration, cluster-analysis

I have a original dataframe (volume purchased by each customers for different products) having multiple columns as below:

[Please click here to refer example of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/69kYp.png)

My objective is to do clustering for each two products from original dataframe. for simplicity I tried taking a one case to do a clustering by taking customer, product1 and product 2.
my dataframe looks like this (customer column is ignored and just two products' data is taken)
df =
[Please click here to refer example of dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPMRd.png)

consider the codes below which I have used for clustering and visualization.

```
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
wcss = []
for i in range(1, 11):
    kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = i, init = 'k-means++')
    kmeans.fit(df)
    wcss.append(kmeans.inertia_)
plt.plot(range(1, 11), wcss)
plt.title('The Elbow Method')
plt.xlabel('Number of clusters')
plt.ylabel('WCSS')
plt.show()

# 4 clusters
# Fitting K-Means to the dataset
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4, init = 'k-means++')
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(df)

# Visualising the clusters
plt.scatter(df[y_kmeans == 0, 0], df[y_kmeans == 0, 1], s = 20, c = 'red', label = 'Cluster 1')
plt.scatter(df[y_kmeans == 1, 0], df[y_kmeans == 1, 1], s = 20, c = 'blue', label = 'Cluster 2')
plt.scatter(df[y_kmeans == 2, 0], df[y_kmeans == 2, 1], s = 20, c = 'green', label = 'Cluster 3')
plt.scatter(df[y_kmeans == 3, 0], df[y_kmeans == 3, 1], s = 20, c = 'yellow', label = 'Cluster 4')
plt.title('Clusters of customers')
plt.xlabel('Product1 (000 TO)')
plt.ylabel('Product2 (000 TO)')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

this works fine for one pair but my objective is to do for each of the two product combination from my original dataframe.

I tried searching for this and used for loop and iteration but not able to achieve my end goal. I am not that expert in looping and have started using python from few months..your help will be highly appreciated..

You can fix no . of clusters as 4 in your answer.
Let me also paste below what I tried so far for this and still figuring out what next.

Please let me know if I am not clear in my questions..or I need to add more details..Thanks a lot in advance

```
from  itertools import combinations


from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
```

[edit]..below is my latest code..to make more simple..I am trying to iterate below code used for one pair for all pair combinations

```
# kmeans for one pair

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4, init = 'k-means++')
X=df.iloc[:, [0,1]].values
kmeans.fit(X)
y_kmeans = kmeans.fit_predict(X)
```

## kmeans loop

```
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4, init = 'k-means++')
combos = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
for combo in combos:
    for i in range(0,len(combos)):
        X=df.loc[:,combos[i]].values
        kmeans.fit(X)
        y_kmeans=kmeans.fit_predict(X)
```

loop once gave me only last pair's output whereas it should give me all the pair's output..I am not sure, what I am missing here..

Answer (score 0):

You can use `itertools.combinations` to create all the pairwise combinations and then `fit` all the models in a `for loop` appending them into a `list` like:

```
from itertools import combinations
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans

combos = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
models = []
for combo in combos:
    model =  kmeans.fit(df[list(combo)]
    models.append(model)
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried combos and it worked fine for me in creating all the pair combinations but for loop is not fitting the model. using the above loop is returning combo as last pair of elements from combos

Comment: I have pasted a code below which I have used..I am getting y_kmeans as cluster output but it gives me only one column..i.e. it gives output of only last pair of elements and not all pair of elements from combos

Comment: combos = list(combinations(df.columns,2))
kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters = 4, init = 'k-means++')
for combo in combos:
    kmeans.fit(df[list(combo)])
    y_kmeans=kmeans.fit_predict(df[list(combo)])                                                      @kull1n

Comment: if you want to keep track of every model you can store them into a list like the edit shows